# Any way to configure fsck_hfs to use more memory to speed up verification of Time Capsule images?

Tags: backup, time-machine, time-capsule, preferences, fsck-hfs

Periodically Time Machine verifies sparsebundle backups with fsck_hfs. When the sparsebundle is on a Time Capsule (TC) it does this by creating a partial and much smaller representation of the sparsebundle on the TC, transferring the result to the Mac into

```
/private/var/db/com.apple.backupd.backupVerification
```

and then running `fsck_hfs` on it locally (it mounts the local sparsebundle as can be seen with `diskutil list`).
The problem is that it takes a very long time for `fsck_hfs` to verify this representation of very large TC sparsebundles (e.g. >24hrs).

[This leaves the `timemachine` process showing in the menu as if it was stuck 'verifying' with the real Time Capsule disk apparently no longer mounted under `/Volumes` - which confuses many into thinking the process has died]

`fsck_hfs` is launched by its parent process `backupd` with the parameters `-f -n -x -E`. There are various posts about `fsck_hfs` working much more efficiently if allowed to use more memory (`-c` option). By default (at least on my system) it seems to be limited to 3Gb.

My question is, is there any way to pass a config that might cause `backupd` to launch `fsck_hfs` with the additional (`-c`) parameter and so run faster?

Comment: `tmutil(8)` ( CLI to `backupd` ) doesn't permit to add this useful parameter.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there's no configuration file or GUI part of the setup that you can use to force Time Machine to let `fsck_hfs` use more than the default amount of RAM for caching.

There's however a kind of "workaround" for making this work anyway. You replace `/sbin/fsck_hfs` with a new program (script or binary) that checks if it is run by Time Machine, and if so adds "-c 8G" (or whatever you want) to the command line parameters given to fsck_hfs. If it not run by Time Machine, just run `fsck_hfs` with the given parameters.

If you're on a recent macOS, you'll need to disable SIP in order to replace `fsck_hfs`.

Comment: Nice trick . I used it with sucess to insert useful arguments to `bootpd` directly called by `/usr/libexec/InternetSharing`.